# template argument deduction/substitution failed: is there no first, second for map?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, stdmap, stl-algorithm

I wish to sort the a `std::map` using the stl `std::sort()` but getting error on [geeksforgeekside](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/L2FIeVS0xu)(cannot paste the whole error please see the link)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int,int> m{
        {1,11},
        {2,5},
        {3,0}
    };
    sort(begin(m),end(m),[](auto a, auto b){return a.second < b.second;});
    for(auto i: m)
        cout<<i.first<<" "<<i.second<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried

```
sort(m.begin(),m.end(),[](pair<int,int> a, pair<int,int> b){returna.second < b.second;});
```

but problem remains same is there no `first`, `second` for `std::map`??

Comment: `std::map` does not work this way. The only container that can be practically sorted is `std::vector`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `std::deque` and `std::array` would like a word with you

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<const int, int>> v{m.begin(), m.end()}; std::sort(v.begin(), ..);`

Comment: I can't understand why are people downvoting it? If I would already know why will I ask the question?? Writing a comment down with the reference link to what am I missing is better than just downvoting.

Comment: @Jarod42 this won't work, since a pair with a const data member is not copy/move-assignable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `std::sort()` to sort a `std::map`.

As you can see, in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), the requirement for `std::sort()`

> Type requirements: RandomIt must meet the requirements of ValueSwappable and RandomAccessIterator.

and a iterator to `std::map` isn't a RandomAccessIterator (like a iterator to a `std::vector` or a `std::deque`).

Anyway, `std::map` is a sort of self-sorted container.

Do not make sense sort it. Make sense, if you want, sort it according another comparator, and you can make this explicating the third template parameter of `std::map` (default: `std::less`, according the key`).

Answer (score 0):

It's a map, it's sorted by design on the key.

You cannot sort it on the value.

Also, not use `bits/stdc++.h`.

Comment: but see here the last code at line 41 http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/24427/ isn't he doing the same??

Comment: No, look at the code `sort(v.begin(),v.end(),Sort_by);`, he's doing this on a vector.